# How to MagicMock Airflow context in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am a new-bee to Python/Airflow and trying to use MagicMock for unit test cases.
I was able to use it in few cases but in one case I am struggling to get it working.

Method which I want to test (UT):

```
    def resolve_sensitive_params(self, localvalue_paramset: dict, context, **kwargs):
            tenantname = context[strings.str_dag].params[strings.str_AF_tenant_name]
            api_url = "https://abcd.com/uri"
            apiurl = f"{api_url}/v3/int/{tenantname}/localsecrets"
            *
            *
            *
            return latest_secret_vals
```

In my test case method I want to mock 'context' or I need to send sample dict/object which will work in the above method.

I have tried few things like below, but did not work for me -

```
    context = MagicMock()
    context.dag.return_value = MagicMock({"params":{"o9AF_tenant_name":"test"}})
    #context.return_value = {"dag": "test"} # o9AF_tenant_name
    #context.return_value = MagicMock(tenant_name="testtenant")
    #context.dag.params.o9AF_tenant_name = "testtenant"
    #context[strings.str_dag].params[strings.str_o9AF_tenant_name] = MagicMock("okok")
    make_request.return_value.json.return_value = {"ParameterValue": "secretval"}
    
    response = dag_init.resolve_sensitive_params(secret_pramset, context)
    print(response)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mahendra

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create `context_mock`, `params_mock` and connect them as shown below,

```
context_mock = MagicMock()
dummy_str_dag = {string.str_dag: your_object}
context_mock.__getitem__.side_effect = dummy_str_dag .__getitem__
        
params_mock = MagicMock()
dummy_param = {strings.str_AF_tenant_name: your_object}
params_mock.__getitem__.side_effect = dummy_param.__getitem__
        
context_mock.__getitem__.return_value = params_mock
```